# How can I get a character from a string pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm passing a `std::string` pointer to a function and I want to use this pointer to access and modify characters in this string.

For now, the only thing I am able to do is print my string by using the `*` operator but I cant't access only one character. I tried with `*word[i]`, `*(word + i)` where `word` is my pointer and `i` is an `unsigned int`.

For now I have this.

```
#include <iostream>

void shuffle(std::string* word);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string word, guess;

    std::cout << "Word: ";
    std::cin >> word;

    shuffle(&word);
}

void shuffle(std::string* word)
{
    for (unsigned int i(0); i < word->length(); ++i) {
        std::cout << *word << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Lets say I type the word *Overflow*, I want to have the following output:

```
Word: Overflow
O
v
e
r
f
l
o
w
```

I'm quite new to C++ and I'm not a native English speaker so please excuse the mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to pass the `word` parameter to the function?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This function will modify the string later.

Comment: Then just use a reference. There's no need to use apointer for that purpose.

Comment: To answer your question directly:  `(*word)[i]`.  The `(*word)` dereferences the pointer, returning a string variable. The `[i]` returns the character from the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know that you have an object, pass it by reference. Then access the object as usual.

```
    shuffle(word);
}

void shuffle(std::string& word) // Not adding const as I suppose you want to change the string
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << word[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference aside from character used in the declaration?

Comment: The reference allows you to use the instance like a normal instance on the stack. No pointer syntax required. It essentially "hides" the pointer from you.

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad Aside that, is there other reasons to use a reference instead of a pointer? Why is this the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Because you know that you have a "unique" string (you cannot reassign the reference), whereas a pointer may be `nullptr` or change.

Comment: @o2640110 you got the question backwards. You should ask instead "Why would you use a pointer?" and the only reason I know is to allow a `nullptr` being passed. Note that most of the time it makes simply no sense for a function to accept a `nullptr` (yours is not even checking and would cause undefined behaviour)